# Find Patterns in Strings

Tags: code-golf, string

In this challence, your task is to locate substrings with a given structure.

## Input

Your input shall be two non-empty alphanumeric strings, a *pattern* `p` and a *text* `t`.
The idea is that each character of `p` represents a contiguous non-empty substring of `t` which occur next to each other, and `p` represents their concatenation.
Identical characters correspond to identical substrings; for example, the pattern `aa` represents any non-empty square (a string obtained by concatenating a shorter string to itself).
Thus the pattern `aa` can match the substring `byebye`, with each `a` matching `bye`.

## Output

If the text `t` contains a substring that `p` matches, then your output shall be that substring, with colons `:` inserted between the strings that correspond to characters of `p`.
For example, if we have `t = byebyenow` and `p = aa`, then `bye:bye` is an acceptable output.
There may be several choices for the matching substring, but you shall only output one of them.

If `t` does not contain a matching substring, your output shall be a sad face `:(`.

## Rules and Clarifications

Different characters of `p` can correspond to identical substrings, so `p = aba` can match the string `AAA`.
Note that the characters must correspond to non-empty strings; in particular, if `p` is longer than `t`, the output must be `:(`.

You can write a full program or a function, and you can also change the order of the two inputs.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Test Cases

Given in the format `pattern text -> output`.
Note that other acceptable outputs may exist.

```
a Not -> N
aa Not -> :(
abcd Not -> :(
aaa rerere -> re:re:re
xx ABAAAB -> A:A
MMM ABABBAABBAABBA -> ABBA:ABBA:ABBA
x33x 10100110011001 -> 10:1001:1001:10
abcacb 0a00cca0aa0cc0ca0aa0c00c0aaa0c -> c:a0aa:0c:c:0c:a0aa
abccab 0a00cca0aa0cc0ca0aa0c00c0aaa0c -> a:a:0c0:0c0:a:a
abcbcab 0a00cca0aa0cc0ca0aa0c00c0aaa0c -> :(
abcbdcab 0a00cca0aa0cc0ca0aa0c00c0aaa0c -> 00:c:ca0aa0c:c:0:ca0aa0c:00:c
```

Comment: The powerset of all substrings? Why not!

Comment: @orlp It's only ``O(2^((n * (n + 1))/2))`` :P

Comment: What does a digit in the pattern string signify?

Comment: @feersum It is a character, so it is essentially the same as any other character.

Comment: @ThreeFx I'm unsure because the first paragraph refers only to "letters" in the pattern.

Comment: @feersum In Rules "different *characters* of ``p`` can ..."

Comment: @feersum Digits are simply handled as characters. I've replaced "letters" with "characters" in the spec.

Comment: Anything I come up with will be horribly inefficient...

Comment: @mbomb007 Efficiency is of little concern here. My reference implementation runs in exponential time. :P

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 207 bytes

```python
import re
h=lambda x:"a"+str(ord(x))
def g(a,b):
 c,d="",set()
 for e in a:
  c+=["(?P<"+h(e)+">.+)","(?P="+h(e)+")"][e in d]
  d.add(e)
 f=re.search(c,b)
 return f and":".join(f.group(h(e))for e in a)or":("
```

Call with `g(pattern, string)`

Uses the `re` module to do most of the work.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45) (ES5.1), 198 bytes

**Since ES6 was released in June 2015, I post the ES5.1 version of the code together with the ES6 equivalent, but declare ES5.1 version as the main answer.**

Greedy match, so the first case returns "Not" instead of "N".

```javascript
function(a,b){c=[o="indexOf"];r=a.split("");return(m=RegExp(r.map(function(i){return(e=c[o](i))>0?"\\"+e:(c.push(i),"(.+)")}).join("")).exec(b))?r.map(function(x){return m[c[o](x)]}).join(":"):":("}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI9b4MwEN35FZYnW0mJaTYjGhGpY1KpK2EwxrRuE4wMiaii/Pb0jhCGTBG@r3f3TmfOP@qkWu1t0720jS2NP7j61/xdT8qTiiTkWh1r3VlXMzUv@FknmUuorUvTf1Q0j32iwrbZ245RymNvuqOv2SH5NF/vfcN8eFANmzpYfh4rTKIzlwPA38SK7nZ0ZiTTYXNsvwGcUxbOOOUXHv44W2NrHpreaFZwvnpo2t@bkkM2NO15PhEl5ZJKRi/XOMAbadWaFm6VBVSRrevIyxvZ0jlEUwjVGBe6fECgxBv8EPNGDgczfU/SdZqma0ykMkVss9kguAZ8lCEJVk5q4C6XPYlEJER0FyyMhET3rsaJlC6IUEJorYRSYMToAAQWHORqiaAUWmpUGIx8rZ7hK4lkMQj4I7d4jjz9vaJ8jiAEjDkmcODJxwQN8jionCcMl2eJq24b5OQcEIS8aY/7Dha6wBdDBgVN0S5uL8byOCDa1a3bm3DvvljFbqQsyucjP3vN@eQvc2Bcrv8)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) (ES6), 141 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>(c=[o="indexOf"],r=[...a],m=RegExp(r.map(i=>(e=c[o](i))>0?"\\"+e:(c.push(i),"(.+)")).join``).exec(b))?r.map(x=>m[c[o](x)]).join`:`:":("
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLBboMwDL3zFVFOiUrTsN5ShYpKO7aTdmVIDSF0VC1B0FZI076dxZBy2KkisZ@f/SwL56weqtNt1dyWtS3MUMpByTiXMdEytRJXdWH6jxJnYStTxpjKwqv8NKf3viEtu6qGVK7WSJ3ajFSUxnyLv77wwgiiWXPvvh0ZYsIWFFPKzraqj0fKTG80ySndTi16GV/TsUNPM18ljgILgodN8FAt0qozHZIoDbBCB3tDyxgdcOiiOXTFEOe6@Me4ktbAB1xrxHgg0/co2SVJsoNEIhLg9vs9kDvH@zsmnRezGbXrdY8iHnEePS8URlwAfBo/kdI54opzrRVXyjnugaOcdwC0WgApuBYaDARer9UreiVAzMfrsNfmr4nnv5cXrwk4d2P6BAw8Y0jgINsEpW0RgeVVyJbTBin6CRBQrenul5tb6AqeBhqNawp@Nb2Oim4CpG3d2YthF3siJZlEaZTRJ3zLaOh7pevMKX6HPw)

Takes the arguments in currying syntax: `f(a)(b)`

Explanation (and ungolfed):

```javascript
function matchPattern(a, b) {                   // Main function
 var c = ["indexOf"];                           // Array used for the capturing groups
 var r = [...a];                                // Split the pattern first
 var m = RegExp(r.map(function(i) {             // Create the regex
  var e = c.indexOf(i);                         // Check if the character is found before
  if (e > 0)                                    // If so
   return "\\" + e;                             // Append the back reference to the regex
  else {                                        // If not
   c.push(i);                                   // Append the character to the array
   return "(.+)";                               // Append a capturing group to the regex
  }             
 }).join("")).exec(b);                          // Execute the regex
 if (m != null)                                 // If the pattern matches the string
  return r.map(function(x) {                    // Replace each letter
   return m[c.indexOf(x)];                      // With the corresponding substring
  }).join(":");                                 // And join them with ":"
 else                                           // If there is no match
  return ":(";                                  // Return ":("
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 35 bytes

```
sᵗ~cᵗXlᵛ∧Xzdz≠ʰ∧Xt~ṇ{Ḷ∧":"|}ᵐ.∨":("
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Oh81NdQ@3Drhf/HDrdPrkoFERM7DrbMfdSyPqEqpetS54NQGELuk7uHO9uqHO7YBOUpWSjUgLXqPOlYoWWko/f8frRCtlKiko@SXX6IUqwNko3CSklNQuGBJPz@oShCvKBUEwQIVFUC@o5OjoxOY6@vrC@E7gYQgGKLO2Bik0tDA0MDAEIZh9iUmJwHlDBINDJKTEw0SE4GUAZQBFALSQAZMbXIi8WqTSFKcQpxqhVgA)

On not-quite-small inputs, ***very*** slow. I-haven't-actually-done-the-sixth-test-case-but-not-for-lack-of-trying slow. (Probably owing to brute-forcing every partition of every substring, starting with the largest, and then checking if it's a match.) Takes input as a list `[pattern,string]`.

#### Condensed and divided explanation:

`sᵗ~cᵗX`

X is the pattern paired with a partition of a substring of the input string.

`lᵛ`

The pattern and the partition have the same number of elements.

`Xzdz≠ʰ`

No two unique `pattern char, matched substring` pairs share a pattern character. That is, no pattern character maps to multiple substrings, although multiple pattern characters may map to one substring.

`Xt~ṇ{Ḷ∧":"|}ᵐ.∨":("`

The output is the elements of the partition joined by colons, unless something couldn't be done, in which case it's `:(` instead.

#### Monolithic explanation:

```
                                       The input
 ᵗ  ᵗ                                  with its last element replaced with
  ~c                                   a list which concatenates to
s                                      a substring of it
     X                                 is X,
       ᵛ                               the elements of which all have the same
      l                                length.
        ∧                              And,
         X                             X
          z                            zipped
           d                           with duplicate pairs removed
            z                          and zipped back
              ʰ                        has a first element
             ≠                         with no duplicate values.
               ∧                       Furthermore,
                 t                     the last element of
                X                      X
                  ~ṇ                   with its elements joined by newlines
                    {      }ᵐ          where each character of the joined string
                     Ḷ                 is a newline
                      ∧                and
                          |            is replaced with
                       ":"             a colon
                          |            or is passed through unchanged
                             .         is the output.
                              ∨        If doing any part of that is impossible,
                                       the output is
                               ":("    ":(".
```

Comment: It's been more than an hour and it still hasn't done the sixth test case... maybe it actually doesn't work? It's using more than its share of processor...

Comment: Okay, either I underestimated the time complexity of using multiple layers of hard brute force, or this is broken in some way, because it still hasn't done the sixth test case

Comment: I've shut it down now because if it takes three hours I'm not sure how much longer I'm willing to wait

Comment: Can shave three off with `z₂`, but bumping this with an edit doesn't seem appropriate.